# How to proceed to find the new quadratic, the forward and the backward errors?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Considering the quadratic equation:

$$ (x-1)(x-2) = x^2 - 3x + 2$$

which has exact roots, $x_1 = 1 \quad and \quad x_2 =2.$

Supposing that a numerical algorithm finds approximate roots equal to $ \hat x_1 =1.1 \quad and \quad \hat x_2=1.9,$

I am quite confused on how to proceed with this question.

Could anyone please show me or walk me through how to:

1. for each approximate root, find a **new quadratic** which is as close to the **original quadratic**, as possible, and for which the approximate root is the exact root.
   That is, for each approximate root, find a δ such that $ x^2 - 3x + 2 + δ$ has the approximate root as an exact root.
2. find the **backward error** and **relative backward** error for each approximate root

Comment: Note that the sum of the roots remains $3$ in the tweaked quadratic and in either case one of the roots is known exactly so the other root of the tweaked quadratic can be deduced from the sum.

Comment: @MarkBennet I am not sure that I am understanding correctly what you are saying. Which tweaked quadratic are you referring to? Am I not supposed to derive my own one?

Comment: The tweaked quadratic is the one with $\delta$ in. I am just pointing out that: given the coefficient $-3$ remains the same, and given one root is known exactly, the other root can be determined and hence the quadratic and hence the value of $\delta$. I would suggest that would constitute progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $$p(x,\delta) = x^2 - 3x + 2 + \delta.$$ Then $p(1.1,\delta) = \delta - 0.09$ and $p(1.9,\delta)= \delta - 0.09$. Hence, the computed roots are the exact roots of the polynomial $q$ given by $$q(x) = p(x,0.09) = x^2 - 3x + 2.09.$$
The absolute value of the backward error for each root is $0.09$, the difference between the new constant term $2.09$ and the old value $2$. The absolute value of the relative backward error is just $0.09/2 = 0.045$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful and clear to understand